Identifying a tub faucet
I am trying to Identify this tub faucet. It's aboiut 17 yrs old at least. Can anyone help me with that?
This is a picture of it, the handles are clear.


This is somewhat of an educated guess. I recall my son had a tub spout like that in an old apartment bath in Oregon. It was a Delta from the 1970s.
